# Does SQLite3's .import behave differently between the interactive terminal and CLI?

Tags: sqlite

I am experiencing what I believe is unexpected behavior with .import in SQLite3:

```bash
$ rm test.db
$ sqlite3 test.db '.mode csv'
$ sqlite3 test.db '.header yes'
$ sqlite3 test.db '.import ./db/seeds/users.csv tmp_users'
$ test.db '.schema tmp_users'
```

produces

```bash
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "tmp_users"(
  "id,username,email,hashed_password,is_verified" TEXT
);
```

However, if I run these same commands in the interactive terminal, I see the expected:

```bash
$ rm test.db
$ sqlite3 test.db
sqlite> .mode csv
sqlite> .header yes
sqlite> .import ./db/seeds/users.csv tmp_users
sqlite> .schema tmp_users
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "tmp_users"(
  "id" TEXT,
  "username" TEXT,
  "email" TEXT,
  "hashed_password" TEXT,
  "is_verified" TEXT
);
```

The first two rows of `./db/seeds/users.csv` is as follows:

```
id,username,email,hashed_password,is_verified
1,johndoe,johndoe@example.com,$argon2id$v=19$m=64,t=3,p=2$YWJjZGVmZ2g$cADjEaoDq7U0/JTVIUurWZonTZnOzL3I2lOtaSgjk6M,true
```

Is this expected on SQLite
`3.37.2 2022-01-06 13:25:41 872ba256cbf61d9290b571c0e6d82a20c224ca3ad82971edc46b29818d5dalt1`?